# Getting highest frequency with a 2 dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm wondering how to get the most frequently appearing string in a 2 dimensional array?

So for example, if you had:

```
const arr = [['foo','bar','21'],
             ['foo', 'lar','28'],
             ['loo', 'bar','28']]
```

you would see that in column 1 that `foo` is the most frequently occurring string, second column would be `bar` and third column would be `28`

The array I have might not always be this size, so I need to make it so it can take any size.

Here is what I tried, but it's big and doesn't quite work with 2 dimensions:

```
function foo_func(array){
  if(array.length == 0)
    return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      var el = array[i];
      if(modeMap[el] == null)
         modeMap[el] = 1;
   }
return maxEl;
}
```

If anyone has a solution that is a little neater or works would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reduce` into an array, whose values are objects, whose keys are the properties (eg `'foo'`) and whose values are the number of occurrences of that key in the current column:

```js
const arr = [
  ['foo', 'bar', '21'],
  ['foo', 'lar', '28'],
  ['loo', 'bar', '28']
];

const columns = arr.reduce((a, subarr) => {
  subarr.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (!a[i]) a[i] = {};
    a[i][item] = (a[i][item] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return a;
}, {});

const highestInEachColumnEntries = Object.values(columns).map(
  obj => Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce(
      (a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? a : b
    )
);

const highestInEachColumnKeysOnly = highestInEachColumnEntries.map(([key]) => key);
console.log(highestInEachColumnKeysOnly);
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is first rotate the array,.

Then it's easy to get the most common using reduce and filter.

Then finally map your rotated array over the common function.

```js
const arr = [
  ['foo', 'bar', '21'],
  ['foo', 'lar', '28'],
  ['loo', 'bar', '28']
];

const rotated = arr[0].map((col, i) => arr.map(row => row[i]));
const common = arr => arr.reduce((a, b, i, arr) =>
     (arr.filter(v => v === a).length >= arr.filter(v => v === b).length ? a : b));
const result = rotated.map(m => common(m));
    
console.log(result);
```